# Ruby on Rails Set up MS SQL Connection to remote Database in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, rubymine

I want to connect my Ruby On Rails Application ( developed with ruby mine ) with a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 running on an external PC.

I can connect with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio running on the same PC where Ruby mine is running to the remote Database in this way:

```
Server name is: domain.de,PORT\SQLServerName
```

[image]

Then I am connected to this remote database :
[image]

In rubymine I use the Gems:

[image]

Now I can use `adapter: sqlserver` in the `database.yml` without an error.

But I have no clue how to connect to the remote database:

I tired several example configurations like:

[image]

When I run the app in development mode I get this error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tiny_tds-0.6.1-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:77:in `connect': Server name not found in configuration files (TinyTds::Error)
```

[image]

Can Anybody help me with the syntax for the `database.yml` that it can use the input data I
also use to connect with MS SQL Server Management Studio to the remote Database

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it on myself:

Just replace the comma with a double point

```
dataserver: 'domain.de:50021\xxxxxxSQLServer'
```

DAMN YOU WINDOWS

Comment: I wonder if the db server is `'domain.de:50021\\xxxxxxSQLServer'`. Note the ` \\ ` instead of ` \ ` there. And yes, it's about the port number.